# Highcharts - Updating a chart's option after initial render

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to update a chart's option (marginRight for example) and call `redraw()` to have that new value reflected in the chart? Or does a new instance of the chart need to be created for these types of changes?

I think it may be the latter because it sounds like only data or axis values can be altered after the chart is created. I see the documentation for redraw states:

> Redraw the chart after changes have been done to the data or axis extremes

And the new dynamic feature in 3.0 states:

> Through a full API you can add, remove and modify series and points or modify axes at any time after chart creation.

Thank you in advance.

**Update**

My reason for wanting to do this was I had a vertical layout and right-aligned legend that was overlapping my chart. I just realized Highcharts automatically sets the correct marginRight to accommodate for this if one isn't explicitly specified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot modify margin parameter dynamically, so you need to destroy old chart and create new instance.

This feature is one of our target in the nearest future.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to accomplish this without destroying the old chart by setting `Chart.optionsMarginRight` and then calling `Chart.render()`

Comment: @Sebastian
Is this something that you have accomplished yet?

Comment: @SebastianBochan Is there any update regarding this?

Comment: At this moment you can call chart.update() method, which allows you to modify margins.

Docs: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Chart.update

Answer (score 2):

Say you got a chart initialized like this:

```
chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    ...
```

You can change trivial attributes, like its title, like this:

```
chart.setTitle({text: "New title"});
```

And you can refresh the dataset it's using with a new one, like this:

```
chart.series[0].setData(newChartData, true);
```

Where newChartData will contain the array with new data you wish to display

Comment: Thank you Filippos. I'm looking for a way to change an even more trivial attribute. One that does not have a specific method for doing so. Specifically, is there a way to change marginRight? 
I've tried modifying it in `Chart.options` and calling `redraw()` but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: In that case, you will probably need to reconstruct the chart. Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9661250/render-highcharts-after-user-updated-labels